# list of json - javascript - how to parse

Tags: javascript, json, django

I know, this thing was asked like billion times here. but i cannot read the inner json objects from this:

```
{"issuccess": "yes", "downloads": 
"[{\"pk\": 39, \"model\": \"home.accessinfo\", \"fields\": {\"title\": \"weblink test bezugsquelle\", \"accesstype\": \"Kostenpflichtiger Download\", \"weblink\": \"google.de\", \"content\": \"weblink test bezugsquelle\", \"person\": 20, \"date\": \"2014-09-22T13:56:38.647Z\"}}, 
 {\"pk\": 43, \"model\": \"home.accessinfo\", \"fields\": {\"title\": \"wefwef\", \"accesstype\": \"Kostenfreier Download\", \"weblink\": \"google.de\", \"content\": \"\", \"person\": 20, \"date\": \"2014-09-26T17:27:29.336Z\"}}]"
}
```

i cannot get the things inside `[]`. I tried `data.downloads[0].fields` i am getting `undefined`.

I want to be able to loop over `[]`.

Comment: You can't read any objects from there, it isn't valid JSON.

Comment: did you try data['downloads'][0]['fields'] ?

Comment: Fix all the errors in the JSON. Something like http://jsonlint.com/ might help.

Comment: @iCezz — Why would that help? Neither `downloads` nor `fields` contain any characters that are not allowed in identifiers.

Comment: @Quentin my actual data is a valid json. i just updated the question. the former was just a sample data from me where i did mistake while posting

Comment: @Quentin It is valid JSON (except for junk whitespace after "downloads") .. of double-JSON'ed crap.

Comment: @user2864740 — And (before the edit) the use of `'` instead of `"` around some property names.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, well go figure the confusion then :<

Comment: *tldr;* the JSON is being generated incorrectly. Fix it.

Comment: @user2864740 are you telling me this? what do you mean with "incorrectly"?

Comment: @doniyor "downloads" contains a JSON *string* containing JSON. This is caused by an incorrect generation of the JSON from the get-go as it has already destroyed the object graph. If properly generated it should look similar to Lesha's answer (well, only JSON and not a JS Object Literal).

Comment: @user2864740 there is only an escape sign and nothing else is different from lesha's answer

Comment: Anyway a -1 for the paramount amount of confusion such a gross mis-information/edit is causing. And no, it isn't... please look at the current question edit with `"[{\"pk\": 39 .. crap]"`. That is JSON encoded as a JSON *string*. Notice how Lesha's answer has none of those extra `\"s` (which are the result of quotes in from the inner JSON in the JSON *string*).

Comment: @user2864740 yeah sorry, i am reaaaly consufed right now. i am generating this in this way: http://pastebin.com/v3D5KDZ3

Comment: Which is wrong. Remove the `serializers.serialize('json', ..)`. That *generates* a JSON (a string value) which is then re-JSON'ified by `json.dumps(data)` as JSON *string*. (It might actually be appropriate to move the full model *into* the `serialize` step and remove `json.dumps`, but that's a different question, mainly "how do I return a mixed dictionary and Object Result JSON from Django?") - basically use `serialize` *or* `json.dump` but *not both*.

Comment: @user2864740 that was the pain. thanks man. i will try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62035/discussion-between-doniyor-and-user2864740).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see a problem. After fixing typos everything working well for me

```
var data = {
  'issuccess':'yes',
  'downloads': [
    {
      "pk": 39,
      "model": "home.accessinfo", 
      "fields": {
        "title": "weblink test bezugsquelle", 
        "accesstype": "Kostenpflichtiger Download", 
        "weblink": "google.de", 
        "content": "weblink test bezugsquelle", 
        "person": 20, 
        "date": "2014-09-22T13:56:38.647Z"
      }
    }
  ]
};

console.log(data.downloads[0].fields);
```

Comment: @user2864740 — This answer refers to the code in the original version of the question. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26073537/1

Comment: Arg, these entirely-different edits again :<

Comment: Yep, in original question was a problem with `]` and `}` at the end of "json" data

Answer (score 3):

You don't have "inner JSON objects". The `downloads` property is a **string** (which contains another JSON text).

You would have to get the value of `downloads`, run it through a JSON parser, then work with the result.